# Android USB to Java (PC)

Tags: java, android, usb

I am looking for a simple direction pointer here. I am wanting to try communicating from an android tabled to a java program. send/receiving data over USB interface. Help would include API references (like libraries i should look into for both android java and standard java) or links to tuts if you know any or simple ideas. Thanks in advance! I contonue searching.

**EDIT****
I am still lost. I don't know where to begin so I will restate my question in hopes for more answers. I am looking to connect an android tablet to my computer through usb and be able to send/receive string data to a custom java application. I have to use usb as the situation will not permit Bluetooth or wifi. An example would be a java(PC) application that sends an x,y coordinate to an android tablet, and the tablet draws that coordinate and a user touches the screen and the android tablet sends an x,y coordinate to the java application to the pc. I can do this with an arduino so the PC java application is not an issue, just the android java app.

Comment: Want to implement the same in an app that i am building...need help with the implementation?

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be the "[USB Host and Accessory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html)" guide in the Android developer guides.

Comment: Thank you! I mannage to get there in my own and will get back to anyone also following this question to try and give a direct answer.

Comment: Hey, just out of curiosity, is it really possible to send data via USB ? I thought only files/videos/images etc. could be transferred !

Answer (score 0):

If data volume is low you might just copy files back and forth by using MTP file transfer protocol which is readily available on almost any Android device and easy to use.